# Do any of the JPA implementations (or wider Java ORM implementations) support updatable Cursors

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, eclipselink, ibatis

I'm hoping that one of the Object/Relational Mapping (ORM) tools available for Java will meet these requirements:

- Use a JPA or native-SQL query to fetch a large number of rows and return them as **entity** objects.
- Allow for iteration through the rows (entities) and persistence of the current entity after I've made change to it.

I want to do perform a complex batch operation (actually I'm comparing and reconciling known-good data from a file against data in my database) row by row. If it was simpler, I'd just resort to using JDBC and execute some SQL; but in this case I really do get benefits from going directly from beans to the database.

In SQL, I could use an updatable cursor to achieve my goal efficiently.

For reference, I'm testing all this out in an embedded Java H2 environment.

### JPA Query

My first naive attempt was to call on [Query.getResultList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29) which returns the entity beans fine but they're "disconnected". If I call `persistenceUnitUtil.getIdentifier(myEntity)` then it complains that it's not an entity type.

### Hibernate

Then I investigated Hibernate which supports [ScrollableResults](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html). The interface allows me to get hold of individual column values by name, but not the entities.

### EclipseLink

Next up was EclipseLink which supports [ScrollableCursor](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.4/org/eclipse/persistence/queries/ScrollableCursor.html). I held out good hope for this one, using it with:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(jpaQuery);
query.setHint("eclipselink.cursor", true);
CursoredStream cursoredStream = (CursoredStream)query.getSingleResult();
```

Unfortunately `cursoredStream.next();` again returns a "disconnected" version of the entity. So, I can't see a way to write back to the entity.

### Conclusion

I'm currently investigating ways to at least get the entity's @Id passed back as part of a query (unfortunately, I want to keep the tool flexible and sometimes I have strings as keys and other times composite key objects). That would at least allow me to iterate through the rows then lookup and persist each entity individually.

But, what I would prefer is to have a cursor-backed iterator that would fetch me a JPA-connected entity and allow me to make changes to it and persist it.

If this isn't a known feature of one of the ORM tools, I'll probably have to give up and resort to good-old-JDBC.

Comment: have you considered: loading batches of the entities, iterate and update them and Flush the changes in one go, rince repeat?

Comment: That would be fine, but how do I get hold of a batch of "connected" entities? The Query interface gives me "disconnected" ones.

Comment: They are disconnected because you are not in a transaction. While the transaction is live, the objects are connected.

Comment: Hi @Zagrev, that doesn't reflect my experience. As far as I was concerned I was in a transaction.

Comment: If you !do! have an active transaction, your classes must be managed (not detached). If you are sure that you have a transaction active, most likely the JPA implementation you use is broken.

Answer (score 1):

pseudocode (C#)

```
void Execute(ISession session, string filepath)
{
    int page = 0;
    int pagesize = 5000;
    int batchindex = int.MaxValue;
    List<Entity> batch = new List<Entity>();

    TextReader file = new StreamReader(filepath)

    string line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine) != null)
    {
        if (batchindex > batch.Count)
        {
            session.Flush();
            session.Clear();
            batch = session.CreateCriteria<Entity>()
                .AddOrder(Order.Asc(<same order as in file>))
                .SetFirstResult(page * pagesize)
                .SetMaxResults(pagesize)
                .List<Entity>();
            page++;
            batchindex = 0;
        }
        if (database has more rows than the file
        while (!LineIsForEntity(batch[batchindex], line))
        {
            batchindex++;
            // same if (batchindex > batch.Count) as above
        }

        UpdateEntity(batch[batchindex], line);
    }
    session.Flush();
    session.Clear();
}
```

there might be better code depending on the kind of data and the context.

Update: random access using C# which should be efficient while using (N)Hibernate

```
const int pagesize = 2000;
var nextbatch = Enumerable.Repeat(0, pagesize)
    .Select(_ => file.ReadLine())
    .TakeWhile(line => line != null);

string[] batch;
while ((batch = nextbatch.ToArray()).Length > 0)
{
    // ignore results, we only want the entities in cache
    session.QueryOver<Entity>()
        .WhereRestrictionOn(e => e.Id).In(batch.Select(line => ExtractId(line)).ToList())
        .List();

    foreach(string line in batch)
    {
        Update(session.Get<Entity>(ExtractId(line)), line);
    }
    session.Flush();
    session.Clear();
}
```

as said in the comments replace the use of session with entityManager and C# constructs with Java. If the entities are independent you could even parallelize the while with multiple Threads, Sessions.

Comment: Thanks for posting, but I'm not sure how this helps. I have no problem writing code that logically steps through entities and updates them (in fact, I'd choose to iterate through the database results and look up the entities in an in-memory structure; that fits my use case better). My question is specifically around how a JPA implementation can be used to achieve this iterate and update cycle.

Comment: for JPA exchange session with entitymanager. the flow is the same: take one side for iterating and batch access the other side. if the order doesnt match and you need random access then iterate a batch, load corresponding entities with one roundtrip, update them and Flush at once.